# Access not configured YouTube API

Tags: ios, youtube-api

I am attempting to add the ability to view certain videos from YouTube into an iOS app I am creating. I have an API key from Google and have enabled the YouTube API from the Developer Console, as comments are suggesting. This is not the issue.

I have a very simple method that collects the details of a specific YouTube channel from it's ID which I will then use to find all of that channels uploaded videos. The issue I'm having is it says my Access is not Configured. Here is everything I have done:

The method to grab the information (obviously I haven't included my key or the channel ID there):

```
- (void)collectChannelData {

GTLServiceYouTube *service = [[GTLServiceYouTube alloc] init];
service.APIKey = @"API_KEY";
GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForChannelsListWithPart:@"contentDetails"];
query.channelId = @"CHANNEL_ID";

GTLServiceTicket *ticket = [service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        GTLYouTubeChannelListResponse *channelItem = object;
        NSLog(@"%@", channelItem);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
}];  }
```

I have ensured the the YouTube Data API v3 has been switched on in the Google Developer Console, and the Bundle Identifier matches what is in my Info.plist

The error message I receive is:

> Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=403 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.)" UserInfo=0xa3aa0e0 {error=Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project., GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x8a74630: {message:"Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project." code:403 data:[1]}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.)}

I cannot find any reason why this would not work. I believe I am correct in that I should not need to set up a billing account or need oAuth for this specific request. I can also see in the overview for my app on the Developer Console that multiple requests have been received but there is an error for each request. I just can't figure out why it's rejecting it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Thank you, took some digging to find this. I had the same issue with the Translate API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a known issue with Bundle identifier, please omit it for now, and it should work.

You can track the issue here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5770

Answer (score 0):

Have you performed the steps that are listed in this documentation page:

```
https://developers.google.com/console/help/#activatingapis
```

Generally, you need to enable the specific API that you want to access for a specific project. The error message that you receive is pretty clear about it

Comment: Yeah as I said above:
"I have ensured the the YouTube Data API v3 has been switched on in the Google Developer Console"

Answer (score 0):

You should sign up for an API key using the Google Developer Console at:

```
https://code.google.com/apis/console
```

Comment: As in my post above I have already signed up for an API Key, have included that in my project and have enabled the specific API in the Google Developer Console

Comment: then make sure Youtube Data API is turned on.. you could find in the service

Comment: Again, I have said a couple of times in the post and in my reply that I have enabled the YouTube Data API. Thank you for your help but I know that is not a solution to the issue I'm facing.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your bundle identifier from the Google Console.

If that still doesn't work, remove the iOS API key from the Google Console and create a new one without a bundle identifier.