# Youtube API - iOS Key

Tags: ios, api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are using the google API library (objective-c) to try and access YouTube data. I have created an iOS key from Google Console, limited it to a specific bundle id and enabled it. Requests are failing with the error below. I know that it is a known issue while using bundle identifier to generate the key, but want to confirm if this issue still persists or it is resolved now and expected to work?

I tried experimenting from my side and came to the conclusion that it is still an issue. But just want to confirm if anyone tried recently and succeeded or have any workaround for this issue.Just want to ensure an extra security measure if it is resolved by now.

> Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=403 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (Access Not Configured. Please use Google
>   Developers Console to activate the API for your project.)"
>   UserInfo=0xa3aa0e0 {error=Access Not Configured. Please use Google
>   Developers Console to activate the API for your project.,
>   GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x8a74630: {message:"Access Not
>   Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API
>   for your project." code:403 data:[1](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5770)},
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Access Not Configured. Please use Google
>   Developers Console to activate the API for your project.)}

Issues previously discussed:

- [Access not configured YouTube API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519644/access-not-configured-youtube-api)
- [Access Not Configured Error, Even Though Access is Configured](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5770)

Comment: can you share screenshot of your api enable in google console,I worked on it for me it is working fine.

Comment: Please find the screenshots.                                    http://tinypic.com/r/29ngraa/9                                   http://tinypic.com/r/e707ig/9

Comment: Did you limit the iOS Key to a specific bundle identifier?

Comment: what version of SDK are you using?

Comment: YouTube Data API v3,
Xcode 7.3.1,
iOS 9.3.2